# appending API request to another dictionary

Tags: python, api

making an application where I need to get field 'workers' from an API request and pass those to another dict.. dictionary is behaving strangely and I cannot seem to append through `+=` or `.update` like a normal list or tupple.

## main.py

```
# worker_detail - contains a list of filtered workers
# workers - contains a list of all workers

information = {}
reported_workers = []
for person in workers:
    if person['id'] in worker_detail:
        reported_workers += person
        print(reported_workers)
```

If I use the above logic it will only print the fields in a dictionary without and workers..

```
['id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'phone_number', 'hire_date', 'job_id', 'salary', 'commission_pct', 'manager_id', 'department_id', 'id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'phone_number', 'hire_date', 'job_id', 'salary', 'commission_pct', 'manager_id', 'department_id']
```

If I `print(person)` output will be a dictionary containing all the neccessary fields and it's details

```
{'id': 1, 'first_name': 'Steven', 'last_name': 'King', 'email': 'SKING', 'phone_number': 5151234567, 'hire_date': '2021-06-17', 'job_id': 'AD_PRES', 'salary': 24000, 'commission_pct': 0, 'manager_id': 0, 'department_id': 0}
{'id': 2, 'first_name': 'Neena', 'last_name': 'Kochhar', 'email': 'NKOCHHAR', 'phone_number': 5151234568, 'hire_date': '2020-06-17', 'job_id': 'AD_VP', 'salary': 17000, 'commission_pct': 0, 'manager_id': 100, 'department_id': 90}
{'id': 5, 'first_name': 'Bruce', 'last_name': 'Ernst', 'email': 'BERNST', 'phone_number': 5151234571, 'hire_date': '2016-07-17', 'job_id': 'IT_PROG', 'salary': 6000, 'commission_pct': 0, 'manager_id': 103, 'department_id': 60}
{'id': 9, 'first_name': 'Inbal', 'last_name': 'Amor', 'email': 'IMOR', 'phone_number': 5151234575, 'hire_date': '2013-08-23', 'job_id': 'IT_PROG', 'salary': 5000, 'commission_pct': 0, 'manager_id': 104, 'department_id': 60}
```

Comment: `reported_workers` is a list, not a dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`append`, dont `+=`

```py
information = {}
reported_workers = []
for person in workers:
    if person in worker_detail:
        reported_workers.append(person)
print(reported_workers)
```

Comment: It only prints the first loop and skips everything else

Comment: thats because of `if person['id'] in worker_detail:` it has nothing to do with the code I added

Answer (score 3):

Try using a list comprehension:

`reported_workers = [person for person in workers if person in worker_detail]`

If you find yourself looping over a list to make a new list, often you can replace it with this really nifty structure. It will let you abstract away your criteria also. If you want your worker_detail to be a more specific tuning, you can create a function for it and just call that in the list comprehension

```
def is_worker(person_id):
    for worker in worker_detail:
        if worker['id'] == person_id: return True
    return False

reported_workers = [person for person in workers if is_worker(person['id'])]
```

Comment: Sorry but I got excited too early.. it prints only one loop and skips everything else..

Comment: ah, sneaky! Let me try it on my local and see what's happening